# How to compare performance two kinds of coding or controls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, performance

How to compare performance two kinds of coding or controls?. i really want to compare 2 kind of coding :
first kind of coding : 2.065 ms
second kind of coding : 3.065 ms

For example how to compare gridview filling sqldatasoursecontrol or linq method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class is a high resolution timer useful for capturing performance metrics.  Just start and stop it before and after what you are trying to get performance metrics from.

Answer (score 1):

For the most accurate results, you should use a [Code Profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)). My personal favorite for .NET is [RedGate's ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/).

That will not only show you how long things are taking, but where the bottlenecks are which will allow you to figure out how to fix them.

A less formal way would be to introduce some logging in your application using `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` to time how long calls are taking. This won't give you nearly the level of detail about what exactly your code is doing though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StopWatch class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx before and after invoking action